# NHibernate subquery with not mapped column

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have problem with nHibernate.

Let's say there are 2 classes Client and Order

```
public class Client{
 public int Id {get; set;}
 public string Name {get; set;}
 public List<Order> {get; set;}

}

public class Order{
 public int Id {get; set;}
 public string OrderProp {get; set;}
}
```

so there is a relation Client to Order but not Order to Client and I cannot change it.

But in database there is foreign key in Order table (fk_ClientId)

How to define that kind of SQL in nHibernate

```
Select c.Id, 
 c.Name,
 (SELECT TOP 1 OrderProp FROM Order o WHERE o.fk_ClientId = c.Id ) 
from Client c
```

If there will be relation in code Order to Client I can use subquery

```
session.QueryOver<Client>(() => clientAlias)
    .SelectList(list => list
        .Select(c => c.Id)
        .SelectSubQuery(
            QueryOver.Of<Order>()
                .Where(o => o.Client.Id == clientAlias.Id)
                .Select(o => o.OrderProp)
                .Take(1)
            )
    )
```

Maybe in Where I can hardcode field which should be used to join ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var dto = session.Query<Client>()
    .Select(c => new { c.Id, OrderProp = c.Orders.OrderByDescending(e => e.Updated).Select(e => e.OrderProp).First() })
    .ToList();
```